# Multiple Ajax calls while authorization of angular application

Tags: angularjs

App has two types of roles: 'adam' and 'eve' An user can have one or the other role.

Angular service to get the roles:

```
app.factory("AuthService",function($http, $q){
    var user = undefined;
    return {
        getRoles : function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if(user !== undefined){
                deferred.resolve(user.auth);
            }else{
                $http.get("./rest/auth", {
                }).then(function(result){
                    user = result.data;
                    deferred.resolve(user.auth);
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

Routing is done as follows:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/adam", {
            templateUrl: 'templates/adam.html',
            controller: 'AController'
        })
        .when("/eve", {
            templateUrl: 'templates/eve.html',
            controller: 'BController'
        })
        .when("/", {
            resolve: {
                load : function($q, $location, AuthService){
                    var defer = $q.defer();
                    AuthService.getRoles().then(function(data){
                        if(data === 'adam'){
                            $location.path('/adam');
                        }else{
                            $location.path('/eve');
                        }
                        defer.resolve();
                    });
                    return defer.promise;
                }
            }
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });;
}]);
```

I need to get roles in controller as well to perform certain operation. Controller code:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    AuthService.getRoles().then(function(data){
        // some operation
    });
});
```

On navigating to '/', ajax is called twice since both resolve and controller function calls AuthService.getRoles(). How can i restructure the code so that ajax is called only once?

Comment: hi, i have updated my code

Comment: If one call is going through OPTIONS method and other using GET/POST method, the problem gets resolved by using following code:

$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

You can try replacing content type as application/json . I don't know the reason why it happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would change your factory to something like this so that they hook into the same promise :

```
app.factory("AuthService", function ($http, $q) {
    var userPromise;
    return {
        getRoles : function () {
            if(!userPromise){
                userPromise = $http.get("./rest/auth", {}).then(function(result){
                    return result.data;
                });
            }

            return userPromise;
        }
    };
});
```

This creates a promise if it's not set, to get the data. Every call after that will have the promise created so it'll just hook into the initial one and not make subsequent calls. The reason it's not working for you is because your user only gets set after the $http.get so the second time through it still sees it as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand:

couldn't you just do (in your controller):

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    if($route.current !== '/'){
      AuthService.getRoles().then(function(data){
      // some operation
    }
  });
});
```

This maybe undefined but you get the idea (maybe a emit->broadcast->on would give you the route params reliably. A $timeout could help.($timeout 0 is not dirty in angular it just sets it last in the queue).

Comment: Well, what i mentioned is just a use case. What i want is to prevent multiple ajax call from service if another call is pending or data is available.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

**Factory**

```
app.factory("AuthService", function ($http, $q) {
    var user = undefined;
    var authSvc = null;

    return function () {
        if (!app.isSvcInstance) {
            authSvc = null;
            this.getRoles = function () {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                if (user !== undefined) {
                    deferred.resolve(user.auth);
                } else {
                    $http.get("./rest/auth", {

                    }).then(function (result) {
                        user = result.data;
                        deferred.resolve(user.auth);
                    });
                }
                return deferred.promise;
            };
            authSvc = this;
            return this;
        }
        return authSvc;
    };
});
```

**Controller**

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    app.isSvcInstance = true;
    var auth = new AuthService();
    auth.getRoles().then(function (data) {
        // some operation
    });
});
```

**Alternative**

```
app.factory("AuthService", function ($http, $q, $cacheFactory) {

            var cacheSvc = $cacheFactory("myCache");

            return {
                getRoles: function () {
                    var cacheFac = cacheSvc.get("authCache");
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    if (!cacheFac || cacheFac.length === 0) {
                        $http.get("./rest/auth", {

                        }).then(function (result) {
                            cacheSvc.put("authCache", result.data);
                            deferred.resolve(result.data);
                        });
                    } else {
                        deferred.resolve(cacheSvc.get("authCache"));
                    }
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check $q.all function

Basically it combines multiple promises in one